# Find term in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Say if I had a list of pokemon:

```
not_e =     {"Bulbasaur": ["Overgrow", "Tackle", "Leech Seed"],
                  "Charmander": ["Blaze", "Scratchy", "Growl"],
                  "Squirtle": ["Torrent", "Tackle", "Tail Whip"],
                  "Pikachu": ["Static", "Tail Whip", "Thunder Shock"],
                  "Haunter": ["Levitate", "Hypnosis", "Spite"],}
```

And say if I wanted to choose a random Pokemon, which I done like this:

```
random_pokemon = ["Bulbasaur", "Charmander", "Squirtle", "Pikachu", "Haunter"] 
rand_pokemon = random.choice(random_pokemon) 
print("Your pokemon is: " + rand_pokemon)
```

How would I search for the random pokemon in that dictionary, and get the list of powers out from it?

Comment: Why not `not_e[rand_pokemon]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# this randomly selects the character.
character = random.choice(not_e.keys())

# this prints the powers of the randomly selected characters.
print not_e[character]
```

If all you want is the powers of the randomly selected pokemon characters, you can combine both the statements, like this

```
print not_e[random.choice(not_e.keys())]
```

Comment: I think this will print a list, he might want a more user-friendly output

Comment: @Dunno But the question says `get the list of powers out from it`, right?

Comment: right, just saying. Maybe I'll just post an alternative answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the list of powers in a more user-friendly format use:

```
print ' '.join(not_e[character])
```

this will print all the powers separated by spaces. If you want to separate them with new lines use

```
print '\n'.join(not_e[character])
```